Open-edx customization
My client has asked to use this open-edx repository as our LMS,
https://github.com/openedx/edx-platform
Now this project is opensource and client has asked to do some changes in the frontend of this project. I have looked into it and it is extremely big and complex codebase.
Is it possible to do customization and if so, how do I get started with the frontend customization?

I don't think this is a good idea. How are you planning to sync the upstream changes? What about contributing to the original repository?

What if the requirement is not to sync with the original repo. Is it allowed and possible

Then this is a stupid requirement. What if on upstream there are some very useful new features? What if there are critical vulnerabilities fixed on upstream?
